# Increase String by Sequential Index

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

In a file dealing with climatological variables involving a running mean with hours, the hours progress in sequence.

Is there a `sed`/`awk` command that would take that hour (string) in the file and then change it by two, so next time the file is read its (202) and so on to (204) etc...

See the number being added to 'i' below.

```
 timeprime = i + 569 
 'define climomslp = prmslmsl(t = 'timeprime' )
```

My goal is to increase the number in this case, 569, by one each time the file runs through other commands involved in processing the data.

The next desired number next to i would be

```
timeprime = i + 570 (where 569 is increased by one)
```

after that...

```
timeprime = i + 571 (where 570 is increased by one)
```

If there isn't a sed/awk command to do such a thing, is there such a thing in any other method?

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: @hallettwx: [edit] your question to have all the relevant information, don't try to add it in comments.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I have provided an example. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Your description says that you want it increased by 2, but then your example shows it increased by 1. Either one is just as easy as the other, but which one do you actually want?

Comment: @abarnert - One would be good, thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure GNU `awk` can do arithmetic (and number formatting, but you don't appear to want a specific number of digits here…), but I don't know about POSIX `awk`, and I don't like `awk` enough to remind myself, so I wrote a Python answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative using awk:

```
awk '/^timeprime = i [+]/{$5+=2} 1' file
```

Starting with this file:

```
$ cat file
timeprime = i + 569 
 'define climomslp = prmslmsl(t = 'timeprime' )
```

We can use the awk command to create a new file:

```
$ awk '/^timeprime = i [+]/{$5+=2} 1' file
timeprime = i + 571
 'define climomslp = prmslmsl(t = 'timeprime' )
```

To overwrite the original file with the new one, use:

```
awk '/^timeprime = i [+]/{$5+=2} 1' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

#### How it works

- `/^timeprime = i [+]/{$5+=2}`

  This looks for lines that start with `^timeprime = i +` and, on those lines, the fifth field is incremented by 2.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this in Python (or Perl, Ruby, or whatever other scripting language you like, but you included a Python tag). For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys
def replace(m):
    return '{}{}'.format(m.group(1), int(m.group(2))+2)
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(timeprime = i \+ )(\d+)', replace, line))
```

Hopefully the regex itself is trivial to understand:

```
(timeprime = i \+ )(\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gEcuW4bEDJNs_RtN)

The [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function can take a to be applied to the match object instead of a string as the "replacement". So, lines that don't match will be printed unchanged; lines that do will have the match substituted for the same two parts, but with the second part replaced by `int(number)+2`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand where to exactly implement this in my script, as I am relatively new to python. Would it just be python (script-name), or would that code have to be put in the script that contains the number I want incremented itself?

Comment: @hallettwx The former. This is an entire script, which you'd save as, say, inctimeprime.py, then use by just adding `| python inctimeprime.py` into your shell pipeline, or whatever.

Comment: Hmm, running into trouble, When I execute the script against the desired file that I would like modified, it hangs where  sys.stdin is introduced.

Comment: I don't know how you're trying to run this. I wrote it as a filter, which reads from stdin and writes to stdout. If you'd instead like it to, say, take two filenames as a command-line arguments and read from the first and write to the second, use `with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as fout:`, and then `for line in fin:` and then `fout.write(…)`. The official tutorial explains this in more detail—or, if you show us your script, I could show you how to fit this in. But otherwise, all I can do is guess at what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and tutelage in aiding my understanding in what you did above! Have a pleasant evening.